# extract string using same pattern in a text using R

Tags: r, string, text

I'm trying to deal with text with R and here is my question.

From this source text

```
#Pray4Manchester# I hope that #ArianaGrande# will be better soon.
```

I want to extract `Pray4Manchester` and `ArianaGrande` using the pattern `#.+#`, but when I run

```
str_extract_all(text,pattern="#.+#")
```

I get

```
#Pray4Manchester# I hope that #ArianaGrande#
```

How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work because the character `#` also matches pattern `.+`, and this (I guess) causes `str_extract` to look greedily for widest match. You will need pattern that does not include `#` in itself, such as the one suggested by akrun, for example.

Comment: you need to use the non-greedy modifier  `str_extract_all(text,pattern="#.+?#")`

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
str_extract_all(text, "(?<=#)\\w*(?=#)")[[1]]
#[1] "Pray4Manchester" "ArianaGrande"
```

#### data

```
text <- "#Pray4Manchester# I hope that #ArianaGrande# will be better soon."
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to look for results that match text between two hashes that don't contain a space character.

Something like this: `([#]{1}[^\s]+[#]{1})`